# Django - Parsing formset data in POST is painfully slow

Tags: django, formset

I have a model:

```
class IP(models.Model):
    address     = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    fqdn        = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    available   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    reserved    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    network     = models.ForeignKey(Network, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer    = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

and a form:

```
class IPForm(ModelForm):
    id          = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    address     = forms.CharField(disabled=True,
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'     form-control'}))
    fqdn        = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'     form-control'}), required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'     form-control ip_description'}), required = False)
    customer    = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.all().order_by('name'), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), required=False)
    reserved    = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs=    {'class':'checkbox'}), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = IP
        exclude = ['available', 'network']
```

and a view that creates a formset with the modelformset_factory:

```
def ipDetailView(request, ipIDs=None):
    ipformset = modelformset_factory(IP, form=IPForm, extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if len(request.POST.getlist('ip')):
            #we were sent a list of IP IDs to edit
            if 'clear_btn' in request.POST:
                #just remove the fqdn/description of the posted IPs
                ips = IP.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('ip'))
                for ip in ips:
                    ip.fqdn = ''
                    ip.description = ''
                    ip.available = True
                    ip.save()
                return redirect ('iplistview', networkID=ips[0].network.id)
            else:
                #post the forms so the IPs can be edited
                formset =     ipformset(queryset=IP.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('ip')))
                return render (request, 'ipmanager/ipdetailview.html',     {'formset' : formset})
        else:
            #we were sent a set of IP forms to commit changes for
            formset = ipformset(request.POST)
            if formset.is_valid():
                instances = formset.save()
                return redirect ('iplistview',     networkID=instances[0].network.id)
            else:
                 return render(request, 'ipmanager/ipdetailview.html',
                                                {
                                                'formset'      : formset,
                                                })

    else:
        network = IP.objects.filter(id=ipIDs)[0].network
        formset = ipformset(queryset=IP.objects.filter(id=ipIDs))
        return render (request, 'ipmanager/ipdetailview.html', {'formset' :     formset, 'network' : network})
```

My problem is that the POST section where I'm committing form changes for IPs takes 5-8 seconds to commit, regardless of whether I am committing 1 IP or 20.  The code is pretty straightforward for that part:

```
     formset = ipformset(request.POST)
     if formset.is_valid():
        instances = formset.save()
```

I'm not even sure how to go about figuring out why it's taking so long. I don't have the many-to-many relationships that seem to be bogging down other similar questions.  How do I go about figuring out what's causing the slowness here?

Comment: You can use [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/1.4/) to identify what queries are taking the most time and `EXPLAIN` them. It can also detect potential duplicate queries that can be avoided.

Comment: If you are using PyCharm, you can set breakpoints inside your view and run the server in debugging mode. It has anything you can expect from a decent debugger, like watching variables and running your code line by line.

Comment: Have you used profiling or logged the times to determine that the bottleneck is those lines? If so pleae update your question to include the sizes of those tables and also the indexes used

Comment: why exactly are you doing this? return render (request, 'ipmanager/ipdetailview.html',     {'formset' : formset})

Comment: @e4c5 There is a list view of a network that has all the IPs that belong in the subnet.  There are little checkboxes so you can pick several IPs to modify the information for at once.  I am creating a formset because as far as I'm aware that's the right way to create a view with multiple copies of the same modelform (the IP form in this case).

Comment: seems right. But how about the number of records in the tables?

Comment: @e4c5 There's 1 row in the IP table for each IP being modified.  The number of IPs doesn't seem to affect the time it takes to perform the save() on the formset.

Comment: Have you tried running cprofile and processing the result with kcachegrind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to identify what queries are taking most time, the raw SQL statement, where in your code it was called, and [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) it.

It can also detect potential duplicate queries that can be avoided.

[image: Django Debug Toolbar example]

If ever you notice you have duplicate queries, they can generally be avoided using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related).

Comment: Wildly useful, thank you.  Side question:  if I'm using the test server and doing this on my work machine as a debug, should I expect inflated CPU times?  I'm getting a 10 second request turnaround from the CPU panel.  Just curious how much of that is puny laptop trying to do everything.